# Codeigniter urls working with index.php and also without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I changed my config and replaced it with

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

here is .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but the issue is that both of my url's are working, I want that it should only work without index.php

https://www.example.com/index.php/example/xyz-abc

https://www.example.com/example/xyz-abc

Comment: set you `base_url` in your `config.php` also

Comment: this is my base_url
$config['base_url']  =  "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Comment: @pradeep still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code it may help you.

config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: changed both files but still its also working with index.php

Comment: is it not redirected to non index.php page ?

Comment: replace with last line RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: its redirecting me to non index.php which is right but i want that if I put hard-code index.php then it should not work

Comment: 500 error after putting RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: try to put your project name instead of project

Answer (score 0):

**Please try with below code it's working fine. Rewrite your .htaccess file with below code.**

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|artwork|adminAssets|galleryAssets|html|cache)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]